# Snowflake External Table

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Have a question regarding the Snowflake External Table. As we now the External Tables still a preview feature and still not a General Available. Hence have guys used External table in your production environment and you see any issue ? Snowflake do not recommend to use Preview feature in Production. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

External table feature is publicly available feature as per documentation

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/tables-external-intro.html

Comment: Though it is available to all accounts, it is still a  Preview Feature — Open , as mentioned in the link.